# Map between global sections of a flat morphism is flat

Tags: algebraic-geometry, schemes

> If $f:X\rightarrow Y$ is a flat morphism of schemes then the map $\Gamma(Y,\mathcal{O}_Y)\rightarrow\Gamma(X,\mathcal{O}_X) $ is flat.

This was used in the proof of *proposition 11.48* in the book of Gortz -Wedhorn to prove that one can pullback Cartier divisors under a flat morphism. I have been able to understand the proposition without using this (and using the right definition of the function field) but I still don't find a proof or counterexample for it.

Does someone knows if it is true?

It would be interesting to discuse the case in which $f$ is an open immersion as well. This correspond to the restriction morphisms of the structure sheaf being flat.

Also, of course this is true if both $X$ and $Y$ are affine.

Comment: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/65267/global-sections-of-flat-scheme-also-flat shows that this is not necessarily the case, while https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/01U4 gives something towards the result - it appears that patching construction is to blame.

Comment: oh! I didn't find that. Thank you, it completely answer my question!